# After effect position keyframes motion problems

Tags: after-effects, keyframes, motion-graphics

I'm trying to make a motion of position of shape and I'm getting next:

[image]

In this frame, position getting automatically lower than I desired to. I mean, I want that the 1st keyframe to be 950 px (for example) and the 2nd ketframe to be 930px. But when I do this, automatically, the curve goes to 900px and then, from this location (circled orange in image), goes to 930px.

That I want to do is a transition from 950px to 930px, and not 950 to 900 and then to 930; but AE automatically creates that type of curve.

Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you're not using Linear spatial interpolation on the keyframes.
See this answer:
[Object moving to a position I didn't specify](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/14687/object-moving-to-a-position-i-didnt-specify/14697#14697)

Comment: Thank you! It is solved :)